# Double slit fringe height

Tags: double-slit-experiment

The fringes in the double slit don't appear in a 2D plane as the usual constructive interference analogies usually indicate (i.e. with the water waves). Also the laser, or light source is usually not a perfect 1D beam.

I am aware of formulas to predict fringe separation in the plane parallel to the light source. 
Can we predict the fringe height?
And what are some variables that contribute to the fringe height in 3D space?

Comment: "2D plane as the usual constructive interference analogies usually indicate (i.e. with the water waves)" this is quite an assertion without any links. An nothing, water included, is "perfect" in experiments.  Links please showing data and the "dont appear" claim

Comment: I really just want to know the fringe height.